# Site issue debug set to true

Tags: wordpress

Hello i have a problem with my wordpress site Error :

link to [website](http://murtishi-bau.ch)

> Notice: Use of undefined constant header_top_enable2 - assumed 'header_top_enable2' in /home/onehostscp/public_html/murtishi-bau.ch/wp-content/themes/structure/templates/header-preset-06.php on line 7
>       Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function header_class() in /home/onehostscp/public_html/murtishi-bau.ch/wp-content/themes/structure/templates/header-preset-06.php:34 Stack trace: #0 /home/onehostscp/public_html/murtishi-bau.ch/wp-content/themes/structure/header.php(36): include() #1 /home/onehostscp/public_html/murtishi-bau.ch/wp-includes/template.php(722): require_once('/home/onehostsc...') #2 /home/onehostscp/public_html/murtishi-bau.ch/wp-includes/template.php(671): load_template('/home/onehostsc...', true) #3 /home/onehostscp/public_html/murtishi-bau.ch/wp-includes/general-template.php(41): locate_template(Array, true) #4 /home/onehostscp/public_html/murtishi-bau.ch/wp-content/themes/structure/page.php(28): get_header() #5 /home/onehostscp/public_html/murtishi-bau.ch/wp-includes/template-loader.php(98): include('/home/onehostsc...') #6 /home/onehostscp/public_html/murtishi-bau.ch/wp-blog-header.php(19): require_once('/home/onehostsc...') #7 /home/onehostscp/public_html/murtishi-bau.ch/index.php(17): req in /home/onehostscp/public_html/murtishi-bau.ch/wp-content/themes/structure/templates/header-preset-06.php on line 34

Here is the code header-present-06.php  i searched on google but doesnt find anything i set the debug error to true to see the error i think it is a update error or something,but doesnt know actually what to do thank you

```
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'top-slider' ); ?>

<div class="header-wrapper">

    <?php
    global $thememove_header_top, $wc_thememove_header_top;
    if ( ( get_theme_mod( 'header_top_enable', header_top_enable ) || $thememove_header_top == 'enable' || $wc_thememove_header_top == 'enable' ) && $thememove_header_top != 'disable' && $wc_thememove_header_top != 'disable' ) {
        ?>
        <div class="top-area">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <?php if ( class_exists( 'SitePress' ) || class_exists( 'Polylang' ) ) { ?>
                        <div class="col-md-7 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                            <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'top-area' ); ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-5">
                            <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'lang-area' ); ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-7 social">
                            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'social', 'fallback_cb' => false ) ); ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                        <div class="col-md-9 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                            <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'top-area' ); ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-7 social">
                            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'social', 'fallback_cb' => false ) ); ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <header <?php header_class(); ?><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> role="banner" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/WPHeader">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
                    <div class="site-branding">
                        <?php
                        global $thememove_custom_logo;
                        if ( $thememove_custom_logo ) {
                            ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
                                <img src="<?php echo $thememove_custom_logo; ?>" alt="logo"/>
                            </a>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                            <?php if ( get_theme_mod( 'normal_logo_image', normal_logo_image ) ) { ?>
                                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
                                    <img src="<?php echo get_theme_mod( 'normal_logo_image', normal_logo_image ); ?>"
                                         alt="logo"/>
                                </a>
                            <?php } else { ?>
                                <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"
                                                          rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
                            <?php } ?>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php if ( get_theme_mod( 'header_search_enable', header_search_enable ) || get_theme_mod( 'header_cart_enable', header_cart_enable ) ) { ?>
                    <?php $class = 'col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-6 header__right'; ?>
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <?php $class = 'col-md-9 col-sm-8 col-xs-6 header__right'; ?>
                <?php } ?>
                <div class="<?php echo esc_attr( $class ); ?>">
                    <a href="#menu"><span class="menu-link"><i class="fa fa-navicon"></i></span></a>
                    <nav class="navigation" role="navigation">
                        <?php Structure::top_menu(); ?>
                    </nav>
                    <!-- .site-navigation -->
                </div>
                <?php if ( get_theme_mod( 'header_search_enable', header_search_enable ) || get_theme_mod( 'header_cart_enable', header_cart_enable ) ) { ?>
                    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 hidden-xs">
                        <?php if ( get_theme_mod( 'header_search_enable', header_search_enable ) ) { ?>
                            <div class="search-box hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                                <?php get_search_form(); ?>
                                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                            </div>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <?php if ( class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) && get_theme_mod( 'header_cart_enable', header_cart_enable ) ) { ?>
                            <div class="mini-cart">
                                <?php echo thememove__minicart(); ?>
                                <div class="widget_shopping_cart_content"></div>
                            </div>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

</div>
```

Comment: I can see header_class_() in error it could be header_class()

Comment: Please go to link and check the error of header

Comment: anybone know any solution of that?

Comment: Hello anybody here to help me on this issue